# "Die machen kein Problem für dich" or "die sind kein Problem für dich"?

Tags: grammar

When I want to say

> So they're no problem for you.

in German, which of the two sentences is (more) correct or common?

More context:

I was talking about the two special German words, "Sie" and "du". Then someone asked me if we have the same words in my native language and I said yes in reply. The sentence I asked is about how that person should respond to my sentence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both variants can be used. We tend to use *"Probleme"* in plural when combining with *"machen"*. That would lead to the following:

> Diese machen dir also keine Probleme.
>   Dies ist also kein Problem für dich.
>   Diese sind also kein Problem für dich.

Comment: I'd like to add that the version "Sie machen kein Problem für dich" is not correct. Normally things are a problem, they don't make problems. Drunk people in bars "machen" problems :)

The first example of Takkat is ok, but in combination with für as Gigili suggested it sounds wrong to me...

Comment: All three forms have very different meanings. #1 "Diese" may refer to some persons or items; #2 & #3 "Dies"/"Diese" refers to the problem(s) itself;